# Can't decide if "Model A belongs to Model B" OR "Model B belongs to Model A"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

Consider the two models:

1. `User` => (id: integer, name: string, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime, department_id: integer)
2. `Department` => (id: integer, name: string, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime)

Now, there is a obvious relationship between these two tables. it is

- Each `User` has one department
- A `Department` belongs to many users i.e there are multiple users in a single department

so, I chose epress the same as following as `A belongs_to B`

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :department
end
class Department < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

But as you may know doesn't work & throws the following error:

```
> @user = User.find(1)
> @user.department.name
  Department Load (1.0ms)  SELECT "departments".* FROM "departments" WHERE "departments"."user_id" = 1 LIMIT 1
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::Error: ERROR:  column departments.user_id does not exist
```

After lot of hit & trial. I stumbled on the correct way to define this, which is just other way around i.e `B belongs to A`

```
class Department < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users
end
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :department
end
> @user = User.find(1)
> @user.department.name
Department Load (1.0ms)  SELECT "departments".* FROM "departments" WHERE "departments"."id" = 1 LIMIT 1
 => "HR"
```

Now, this is exact opposite of the way my brain thinks about these associations. So, I am little confused, so if anyone could explain what is going on?

Why does `B belongs to A` & NOT `A belongs to B`?

Comment: Because there's no "belongs_to_many"? A department has many users--I just think of "belongs_to" as a named inverse of that relationship.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `:has_one` relation is a little bit strange at the first look. Consider a user and an account, every account is connected to (belongs to) just one user, from the other side a user has_one account, just one, his account. An account is something that the user owns.

In these cases you use the `has_one` relation on the `User` model and Rails will search for a `user_id` column in the `accounts` table (see the [has_one documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has_one-association) in the Rails Guide).

In your specific case I think is perfecty right to say "a department has many users" and "a user belongs to a department".

Answer (score 2):

You got your models wrong. They should be like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :department
end

class Department < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users
end
```

So, to add a department to a user, you can do this:

```
@user.department.create(:name => 'Science Department')
```

To add a user to a department, you can do this:

```
@department.users.create(:name => 'John')
```

Answer (score -1):

In the first example you need to add column & index to your table in migration file

```
class AddRelationToDeparments < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column, :deparments, :user_id, :integer
    add_index, :deparments: :user_id
  end
end
```

Comment: If a department has many users, then it certainly won't need a user_id on its table. The user, on the other hand, will need a department_id but the OP already has that.